# After installing Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell XPS 7390, integrated camera is not working

Tags: 20.04, camera

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell XPS 7390, integrated camera is not working. Can anybody help to resolve the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not supported according to this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Dell/XPS/XPS-13-7390-2-in-1

So I doubt that this guide below will work but worth a try:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-test-webcam-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa

Another option is to try installing Windows drivers using Wine and/or ndiswrapper.
https://itstillworks.com/convert-windows-drivers-linux-9821.html

Intel develops Clear Linux I wonder if it works under their OS? Create a Live-USB drive and test it out. 
https://clearlinux.org/downloads

Any of those help?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details. Unfortunately none of the options resolved the issue. I think I need to wait until Ubuntu includes new drivers for this camera.

Comment: does anyone know if pre-releases of ubuntu 22.04 (or ubuntu 21.10) have fixed this?